# How to Create or Generate a New UTXO in Bitcoin Core?

Tags: bitcoin-core, utxo

I know how to use Console in Bitcoin Core but not that expert. I would like to ask is there possible for me to generate or create a new UTXO in Bitcoin Core?

All I have with me are the list of TxID which I have yet to use it. I don't know much about the right code for this.

Anyone can advise?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about creating UTXOs for testing purposes or how new UTXOs come into existence generally?

Answer (score 1):

"Creating a UTXO" is the side effect of transacting. It's an abbreviation of "unspent transaction output"

A transaction in Bitcoin consumes a number of UTXOs, and creates a number of new ones, possibly assigned to new owners.

So the answer is: send BTC somewhere (possibly to yourself).

Answer (score 0):

[getnewaddress](https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/wallet/getnewaddress/) will create a new address

Once you send BTC to the address it becomes unspent transaction output (UTXO)

Comment: I have the new address but what I mean is using the code to create and spend UTXO in bitcoin core.

Comment: `UTXO` is unspent output of a transaction https://learnmeabitcoin.com/technical/utxo You have to create an address, address needs to have something to spend, so send BTC to address and then spend it. If looking for commands related to transactions: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/0.20.0/rpc/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I shall follow the link provided.